# Are actions on active window through c# possible?

Tags: c#, windows, automation

I want to write some code, that can automatically do actions on active windows.
For example, if i want to press the ignore button once the window that pops if I insert a new DOK.

i thought of a code that once a specific (known) window pops, it presses a few TABs, and presses Enter.

Can I implement such a code? preferrable in C#.

Comment: Google "c# ui automation".

Answer (score 0):

I thought of several answers to your question because it isn't clear what you are asking. One of these topics might be an area for research:

If you want to press keys for the active window in an application other than the one you are running, you might read about elevated privileges, interprocess communication, and accessing the keyboard with Windows function calls. You can not normally do anything to other applications other than to cause Windows to send it various messages. Thought: how will you indicate when the press the keys if your application is not the active window?

If the active window is one within your application, then you will be better off in the long run by finding a solution that fits C#'s object-oriented model. If you want certain code to be run at times for certain windows (when one is active), you can share code by putting it into a common superclass and having your window classes inherit it. Looking at it this way will be instructive, but you may have to find a somewhat different solution, since it sounds like your window should be inheriting Window's Window class (you can only have one parent class in C#). You could look up "class inheritance" and perhaps "interfaces."

Another solution that isn't so object-oriented for sharing code is to put it into a static function and call this function as needed in the code of your active windows. But ideally, it is code in the active window class that should be manipulating the window. You can put it into a function and then call the function from anywhere in the application that has the "this" reference for the active window.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer - Indeed 
I would like to press keys for the active window in an application other than the one I am running. So I understand it's complicated? Anyway to do it?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in responding. Well, it is a computer; it can be done, although the time investment may be prohibitive. But I really have no idea how to do it which is why I was limited to only suggesting topics for research.